# Trace Tool for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, trace

Is there any tool in QGIS that traces a line like the trace tool (Editor Toolbar) in ArcGIS? I want to draw a line and trace this line back so that I get the beginning and the end of the line at the same position. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: AutoTrace in QGIS 3 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277535/seeking-autotrace-trace-tool-in-qgis-3

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin for QGIS 1.8: TraceDigitize

Author's tip: "Use ctrl-Key to trace, backspace to delete, left mouse click to set a normal vertex and right mouse click to finish.
Uses the snapping options, which may be changed during digitizing (Consider opening the snapping option as dock widget)"

Comment: TraceDigitize is available for QGIS 2.0 http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/traceDigitize/

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to qgis, but KOSMO and OpenJUMP have a tool "autocomplete polygon".
Use these GIS together!

Comment: In ArcGIS for Desktop AutoComplete Polygon is a different tool to [**Trace**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m70000000s000000)

Comment: is an alternative to creating neighboring polygon fast (only polygon).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Trace and autocomplete are two of the biggest things I miss when I'm using OSGeo programs.

Answer (score 1):

As fausto mentioned, there is a "TraceDigitize" plugin for QGIS 1.8, however it works differently than ArcGIS Trace tool. 
Once installed, you should set your snapping settings:
*Settings>Snapping options*. I reccomend gaving the settings open, because the tool is highly dependant on snapping options.
Then, using Trace Edit tool **and holding CTRL key** you can trace along existing feature lines. The tool is a bit quirky, but it's quite OK, if you mess around with snapping options. Just as ArcGis caunterpart, the tool allows you to add vertices manually, by **left clicking.** To undo, you should press **BACKSPACE**.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new plug-in called AutoTrace:

http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/resources/autotrace

Comment: broken link - -