# Seeking AutoTrace/Trace Tool in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, trace

Have made the move to QGIS 3 but am having trouble locating the AutoTrace/Trace tool.

I have enabled advanced digitizing tools where the magnet button sat in QGIS 2.18 but it is not there in QGIS 3. I also can't find any AutoTrace plugins in the QGIS 3 plugin manager.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The tracing tool has moved to the **Snapping toolbar**:

[image: Trace button]

Comment: Wow,... how can we call up the Snapping toolbar? (Sorry to butt in...)

Comment: @Kazuhito - Don't apologise :). Right-click somewhere on the toolbar to get the available panel/toolbar options and it should be listed. Funnily enough, it is not listed in `View > Toolbars`. Perhaps this is a bug...?

Comment: Great, right-click on the toolbar did the trick. Thanks! (Yes, I had been looking at`View` menu only.)

Comment: @Ben - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)