# How to enable tracing in QGIS 3 beyond applications for adding polygon purposes?

Tags: qgis-3, snapping, trace, ring

I have used the [enable tracing feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277535/seeking-autotrace-trace-tool-in-qgis-3) in QGIS 3 to create new polygons (Add polygon feature), and it works very well. However, i have not been able to use it for other purposes beyond that, for example, to create a [ring](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29280/how-to-create-a-hole-in-a-polygon-in-qgis) inside a polygon and similar tasks.

Is it possible to enable tracing for other purposes beyond adding a polygon?

In this moment my only example is creating a ring inside a polygon. I had to create this point by point, and due to the large number of vertex it would be very handy to use the tracing.