# Polygon freehand digitizing

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to digitize a polygon on qgis in freehand?
I would like to create a polygon vector without clicking on each point with the mouse.

Comment: Isn't the mouse freehand? How did you want to do it? Continuously?

Comment: Like this plugin : https://github.com/DocOC86/freehandEditing_3

Comment: If following another feature, see the [trace tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277535/seeking-autotrace-trace-tool-in-qgis-3)